# Class' Function, When called, does nothing

Tags: python, class

So I've been working on this game (I'm a big noob at python and I've only worked on this for like 3 days) and I've been trying to move the Location (Add or Subtract one from Location's x and y values) but the fuction doesn't work. I know because I put a print in the function and the print didn't work at all. What is wrong? (I have created a folder for this project and there is a folder called Decisions containing 2 files.)

Locations.py:

```
class Location:

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def move_forward(self):
    self.y = self.y + 1
    return self.y

def move_back(self):
    self.y = self.y - 1
    return self.y

def move_left(self):
    self.x = self.x - 1
    return self.x

def move_right(self):
    self.x = self.x + 1
    return self.x
```

main.py (Main Function):

```
import Decisions
import Characters
import Locations

def main():
    Player = Characters.Character([], 100)
    Loc = Locations.Location(0, 0)

answer = Decisions.choice_yes_no.choice_yes_no("You woke up, discovering 
that somehow you were in the middle of a dark dungeon. A sword lies to the 
left of you, pick it up? (Yes/No) ")
if answer == True:
    print("You picked up the sword.")
    Player.add_item("Sword")

elif answer == False:
    print("You chose not to pick up the sword.")

answer_2 = Decisions.choice_direction.choice_direction("You stood up, 
patting the dust off your clothes, you looked around. The room was dark and 
you view was limited to a few meters. Where do you go? 
\n(Left/Right/Forward/Back)   ")
if answer == "forward":
    Loc.y = Loc.y + 1
elif answer == "back":
    Loc.move_back()
elif answer == "left":
    Loc.move_left()
elif answer == "right":
    Loc.move_right()

print(Loc.x)
print(Loc.y)

main()  #REMOVE BEFORE USING#
```

The function add_item works just fine, what is wrong? There aren't any errors, it's just when I print the x and y values at the end they stay 0.

Comment: Is it something to do with the scope? Because in my characters I used append to add to a list and it worked just fine.

Comment: Its because you're checking `answer` rather than `answer_2`.

Comment: Loocid I made so the answer coming from the function choice_direction is always lowercase using lower() so that's no problem. Typing anything works but the thing is the Location's x or y doesn't change.

Comment: Loocid Thank you so much it's working fine now. Such a stupid mistake!

Comment: It happens to everyone. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @TheSuperBlock Put `@` before a username to notify them of your comment.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. All the class methods need to be indented in the `class`. And the statements in the `main()` function need to be indented.

Comment: @Barmar they are I just didn't bother to change it when the copy-paste ruined the spacing. I will be more careful next time.